# I need to fix "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, union-all

I have the following query, but I am receiving this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
(select replace((stuff (itemdata,1,66,'')), '<BodyText>', '')as text
 from charts
 where itemtype = 'DocumentItems_RichText' and checksum ='1'
 union all
 select stuff (itemdata,1,66,'')
 from charts
 where itemtype = 'DocumentItems_RichText'
 and checksum <>'1' )AS Content
```

Comment: what is exact ask here ..

Comment: You get that error when you select more that one column/expression in a subquery that should return only one, like a subquery used for `IN`. Are you sure that error is this subquery? It seems to return only one column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Content
FROM
(
 select replace((stuff (itemdata,1,66,'')), '<BodyText>', '')as text
 from charts
 where itemtype = 'DocumentItems_RichText' 
    and checksum ='1' 
 union all 
 select stuff (itemdata,1,66,'')
 from charts
 where itemtype = 'DocumentItems_RichText'
    and checksum <>'1' 
) DS (Content);
```